# Optional non capturing group regex

Tags: php, regex, regex-greedy, regex-group

I'm struggling with a simple pattern where I need to match 3 strings at maximum or 2 at least

It can be :

```
banana-split.taste
```

Or

```
banana.taste
```

What I want is everything after and before the point.
But if a hyphen happens to exist in the string before the point, I want the string in between the hyphen and the point

With my examples it would result like this :

Example 1

```
match[1] = banana
match[2] = split
match[3] = taste
```

Example 2

```
match[1] = banana
match[2] = 
match[3] = taste
```

What I tried is using positive lookahead/behind but I feel I use it badly

`(.+)(?<=\-)(.*?)?\.(.+)`

With this I am able to get nicely the first example, but not the second

Comment: When you are capturing `banana.taste` do you wish to have `taste` in the `match[2]` or `match[3]`?  I am asking how you are programmatically handling the array of matches.  This will dictate the regex function and pattern that is best for your case.

Comment: I'm handling it by isseting the $match[2]. With @Wiktor Stribiżew method it goes well !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negated character classes and an optional group:

```
([^-]+)(?:-([^.]+))?\.(.+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FBMc0z/1)

**Details**:

- `([^-]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `-` as many as possible
- `(?:-([^.]+))?` - an optional group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `([^.]+)` - Group 2: one  or more chars other than `.` as many as possible
- `\.`  - a dot
- `(.+)` - any 1+ chars other than line break chars

Comment: Perfect, working ! Thanks. Got it working with this too `([^-]+)\-?(.+)?\.(.+)` What I missed originally was the `[^-]` part !

Comment: Yes, the negated character class is crucial here. But I also would insist on using an optional non-capturing group, as a best practice when dealing with optional submatches.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with Wiktor's answer; I have a high regard for the quality of his answers.

Purely for educational purposes, I'd like to explain that `preg_match()` is not the only regex-based function to extract substrings from a string.  Consider this one-liner:

Method:

```
var_export(preg_split('/[-\.]/',$str));
```

Inputs/Outputs:

```
$str='banana-split.taste';  // ['banana','split','taste']
$str='banana.taste';  // ['banana','taste']
```

Notice how `preg_split()` does not use capture groups (so no empty capture groups) and doesn't include the (often useless) fullstring match in its output.

I don't know the process that you are using, but if this simplifies your process, then I am glad that I chimed in.

Comment: Oh pretty cool ! Didn't know preg_split had this power ;). But for my case Wiktor's method is more suited. Still voted for you ! Thanx.